# SOAP client in Apache CXF 3.5.0 and Java 17 returning "Marshalling Error"

Tags: java, maven, cxf, cxf-client

**I'm modernizing some java code to version 17 using Eclipse, Maven and Apache CXF 3.5.0 to build a soap client that connects to the WSDL address below.**

> https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL

**Below is my java version:**

```
daniel@pop-os:~$ java -version
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**Below is my pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Java17</groupId>
    <artifactId>Java17</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <cxf.version>3.5.1</cxf.version>
    </properties>
  
    <build>  
        <finalName>Java17</finalName>
        <plugins>   
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
 
    <dependencies>              
    
        <!-- marshalling error loading wsdl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- cxf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  
</project>
```

**Below is my java code:**

```
package com.webservices;

import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.endpoint.dynamic.JaxWsDynamicClientFactory;

public class ClientExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {       
        try {       
            String wsdl = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";

            JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
            Client client = dcf.createClient(wsdl);
            
            Object[] res = client.invoke("CelsiusToFahrenheit", "35");
            System.out.println("Echo response: " + res[0]);
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

**After updating the project using the command "Maven > Update Project" and installing the dependencies, I run the ClientExample.java class and get the following error:**

```
WARNING: Interceptor for {https://www.w3schools.com/xml/}TempConvert#{https://www.w3schools.com/xml/}CelsiusToFahrenheit has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: https.www_w3schools_com.xml.CelsiusToFahrenheit is not known to this context
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:528)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:439)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:354)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:312)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:332)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:318)
    at com.webservices.ClientExample.main(ClientExample.java:27)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: https.www_w3schools_com.xml.CelsiusToFahrenheit is not known to this context
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: https.www_w3schools_com.xml.CelsiusToFahrenheit is not known to this context]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:226)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.writeObject(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:642)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:244)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: https.www_w3schools_com.xml.CelsiusToFahrenheit is not known to this context
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: https.www_w3schools_com.xml.CelsiusToFahrenheit is not known to this context
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:232)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:309)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:45)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:464)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:298)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: https.www_w3schools_com.xml.CelsiusToFahrenheit is not known to this context
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:603)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:114)
    ... 21 more

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: https.www_w3schools_com.xml.CelsiusToFahrenheit is not known to this context
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:528)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:439)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:354)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:312)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:332)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:318)
    at com.webservices.ClientExample.main(ClientExample.java:27)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: https.www_w3schools_com.xml.CelsiusToFahrenheit is not known to this context
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: https.www_w3schools_com.xml.CelsiusToFahrenheit is not known to this context]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:226)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.writeObject(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:642)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:244)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: https.www_w3schools_com.xml.CelsiusToFahrenheit is not known to this context
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: https.www_w3schools_com.xml.CelsiusToFahrenheit is not known to this context
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:232)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:309)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:45)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:464)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:298)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: https.www_w3schools_com.xml.CelsiusToFahrenheit is not known to this context
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:603)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:114)
    ... 21 more
```

**How do I get this code to work properly?**

Comment: did you get it working? am facing same issue